# Why the rotation of a function of 3d using matrix rotation goes in the opposite direction than the rotation of a vector?

Tags: functions, vectors, rotations

When rotating a vector of 3 dimensions with respect to the z-axis, we do $x'=x \cdot \cos{\theta} - y \cdot \sin(\theta)$ and $y'=y \cdot \cos{\theta} + x \cdot \sin(\theta)$.

Using this method, we rotate the vector in counterclockwise. However, if we do this exact method with a 3d function, such as $x^2-y^2$ then the function rotates clockwise.

Why does this differentiation happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the best way to understand this is to look at horizontal transformations of functions of one variable. If you take a function $f(x)$ and want to, say, shift it to the right by 2 units, you do the *opposite* inside the formula by writing a new function $g(x)=f(x-2)$.

The reason you do this is simple. Suppose $f(1) = 7$. If you want this $y$-value of $7$ to happen at $x=3$ for the shifted function $g$, you need to use $g(x)=f(x-2)$, that way when you set $x=3$, you get $g(3)=f(3-2)=f(1)=7$. So even though formulaically we shifted $x$-values to the left by subtracting 2, the effect is to move the graph to the right. The moral you can take from this is that *what you write on the inside of the function is opposite what you see on the graph*.

This reasoning tells you exactly what is going on in your rotation of the 3D function. You put in a counterclockwise rotation on the inside of the function, so the function compensates by rotating its graph clockwise. Formally, let $R$ be the operation of rotating counterclockwise by some angle. Suppose $f(1,3)=7$, and let $g(x,y) = f(R(x,y))$. Where will $g$ take that value of $7$? Well, it'll do so at $R^{-1}(1,3)$, because
$$
  g(R^{-1}(1,3)) = f(R R^{-1}(1,3)) = f(1,3) = 7.
$$
That means $g$ takes the value $7$ at a new point $(x,y) = R^{-1}(1,3)$, which is the vector $(1,3)$ rotated clockwise, so $g$ is the graph of $f$ rotated clockwise.